# Update div with values from checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to be able to update a div immediately when I select any checkbox. I am currently able to do so, however, when I check the "select all" checkbox to select all the checkboxes, it doesn't update my div with the information from my checkboxes.

Here's what I have done so far: https://jsfiddle.net/3rxk043v/2/

My HTML:

```
<div id="item-list"></div>
<p>Total:<span class="total"></span></p>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" class="c-check">select all</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"class="selectcheckbox selectedtotal" name="items" value="Thomas Hobbes_100" data-amt="100">Thomas</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"class="selectcheckbox selectedtotal" name="items" value="Jerry Xavier_150" data-amt="150">Jerry</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"class="selectcheckbox selectedtotal" name="items" value="Sam Edith_80" data-amt="80">Sam</label>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#selectall').change(function() {
    $('.selectcheckbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
 });

$('input[name="items"]').change(function () {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var className = inputVal.replace(/ /g, '_');
    var inputArr = inputVal.split('_');

    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $("#item-list").append('<span class="span_' + className + '"><li>'+ inputArr[0] + '<p>$' + inputArr[1] + '</p></li></span>');
    } else {
        $('.span_'+className).remove();
    }
});

var $calculateselected = $('.selectedtotal').change(function () {
    var v = 0;
    $calculateselected.filter(':checked').each(function () {
        v += $(this).data('amt');
    })

    var left = 2000-v;
    $('.total').html(v);
    $('.amtleft').html(left);
});
$('.selectedtotal:checked').change();
```

Is there anything preventing the updating of the div when clicking on the select all? All the checkboxes become checked but nothing is updated in my div.

UPDATE:
If I were to add ".trigger('change');" to my code, when I select one checkbox (E.g. Thomas) first before selecting the "select all" checkbox, Thomas will be printed twice. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your code :

```
.trigger('change');
```

to be like this

```
$('#selectall').change(function() {
    $('.selectcheckbox').prop('checked', this.checked).trigger('change');
});
```

and keep every thing as is .

Comment: If I were to click on one checkbox first (E.g. Thomas) and then select the "Select all" checkbox, Thomas would be printed twice in my div. Is there a way to stop this from happening? Thank you!

Comment: yes, you have check before adding the span if it is already there or not, you can use this code `if($('#item-list .span_'+ className).length == 0) {$("#item-list").append(...... }`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#selectall').change(function() {
      $("#item-list").html("");
        $('.selectcheckbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
         $('input[name="items"]').trigger("change");
 });
 
 $('input[name="items"]').change(function () {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var className = inputVal.replace(/ /g, '_');
        var inputArr = inputVal.split('_');

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {  //which checkbox was checked
            $("#item-list").append('<span class="span_' + className + '"><li>'+ inputArr[0] + '<p>$' + inputArr[1] + '</p></li></span>');
        } else {
            $('.span_'+className).remove();
        }
    });

    var $calculateselected = $('.selectedtotal').change(function () {
        var v = 0;
        $calculateselected.filter(':checked').each(function () {
            v += $(this).data('amt');
        })
        
        var left = 2000-v;
        $('.total').html(v);
        $('.amtleft').html(left);
    });
    $('.selectedtotal:checked').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item-list"></div>
<p>
Total:<span class="total"></span>
</p>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" class="c-check">select all</label>

<label><input type="checkbox"class="selectcheckbox selectedtotal" name="items" value="Thomas Hobbes_100" data-amt="100">Thomas</label>

<label><input type="checkbox"class="selectcheckbox selectedtotal" name="items" value="Jerry Xavier_150" data-amt="150">Jerry</label>

<label><input type="checkbox"class="selectcheckbox selectedtotal" name="items" value="Sam Edith_80" data-amt="80">Sam</label>
```

Comment: After using trigger, if I were to select a checkbox (E.g. Thomas) first before selecting the "select all" checkbox, Thomas would be printed twice. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: u need remove all items from div  :
      $("#item-list").html(""); before all times